# SAPUI5:Passing a Model from one Controller to another

Tags: model-view-controller, sapui5

I am trying to create a splitapp with the details view having a map updated based on the selection from the master view. Currently I am trying to set a Model in a function that is executed on select of a list item. I am setting the required model using `sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "ModelName");` in the master controller. And in the details controller I am trying to access the model using `sap.ui.getCore().getModel("ModelName").getData();`. But, `sap.ui.getCore().getModel("ModelName")` is coming out as undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to build Component based UI5 applications. If you do so, you can do the model initialization in the component's init function:

```
init: function() {
    // call the init function of the parent
    UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
    // set data model
    var oData = {
        prop: test
    };
    var oModel = new JSONModel(oData);
    this.setModel(oModel);
}
```

If you are using manifest.json, it's much better to define your model there; this model will be available through the whole application; including views and controllers like the i18n or device models which are created similarly.

[Setting up the component.js](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/4cfa60872dca462cb87148ccd0d948ee.html), [Application descriptors](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/8f93bf2b2b13402e9f035128ce8b495f.html) on UI5 Walkthrough page.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have a global model I will suggest you to use the Component as main holder.

In each Controller you can do

```
this.getOwnerComponent().setModel(oModel, sModelName);
```

and than retrieve it with

```
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel(sModelName);
```

Views and Controllers have their own model visibility so it would be local.